# How to integrate stripe payment with existing django form, and only save form on payment success

Tags: django, django-forms, stripe-payments

I have what I imagine is a pretty standard setup, an eCommerce application with a shopping cart, and the ability to store orders in a local database (needed to know what items to order from wholesaler and where to deliver them to).

At the moment, all this functionality is working perfectly. My 'checkout' at the moment allows a customer to enter their details, and then an order is saved, with each order having several order items.

What I want to do, is use this form to send some of the information to stripe, and if a token is received back indicating success, save some (but not all) fields to the local db.

I am not trying to save CC data locally or anything like that, I'm well awawre of security risks and legal obligations like PCI compliance.

I simply want to have one form that customers can use to input their data, and click pay (like most eCommerce sites have), rather than having one form to enter data, and another form to pay with.

The django-stripe documentation is sorely lacking, and the Stripe API documentation seems only have examples for ruby frameworks and javascript, nothing for django.

Is what I want to do possible, and if it is, what is the correct approach?

I can post my models, forms, views and template snippets if needed, but this seems to be a logic and approach question more than a question specific to code.

Comment: On the frontend, do you get the CC data yourself or use one of Stripe's scripts?

Comment: @farooq I didn't make a decision yet, I had checkout.js on a separate page but that is not the approach I want to stick with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having used Stripe, it actually has amazing documentation. What you are looking for is under the `charge` section in the [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=python). You will also need to create a [token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=python) (can be done server-side via HTTPS or client-side via JS).

What you will want to do is actually charge the user via Stripe first, and if the response is successful, input the order information into your database.

An example would be like so:

```
from django.views.generic import View
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_KEY_HERE"


class PaymentView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        card_num = request.POST['card_num']
        exp_month = request.POST['exp_month']
        exp_year = request.POST['exp_year']
        cvc = request.POST['cvc']

        token = stripe.Token.create(
          card={
            "number": card_num,
            "exp_month": int(exp_month),
            "exp_year": int(exp_year),
            "cvc": cvc
          },
        )

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
          amount=2000,
          currency="usd",
          source=token,  # obtained above
          #source="tok_visa", # obtained with Stripe.js (JS)
          description="Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com"
        )

        if charge['captured'] == True:
            Sale.objects.create(product=product, amount=amount)
            return redirect('app:success_page')

        return redirect('app:fail_page')
```

Comment: I've heard that stripe has amazing documentation, but was thrown off when the main links I could see were for ruby frameworks. It likely wasn't as clear to me because I am still learning django/python. Forgive my lack of knowledge,  but I don't recognize where this sample code would go in a django project. It doesn't seem to be a view or a model.

Comment: Also, to clarify, when you mention charging the customer first and saving form data if successful, could this be done in a way transparent to the user, from just one form?

Comment: Yes. You can have a form that `POST`s a Stripe `token` to a view, and use the code I provided to handle the Charge, create an entry in your DB to log the payment, and then redirect the user to a success page. See my updated code above.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! Makes a lot more sense to me now! I'm looking forward to attempting to implement this.

Comment: No problem! It's all about getting one step closer. Keep pushing until you are stumped, and if you need you can always ask a more precise question. Good luck!

Comment: Hybrid, would you possibly be available to answer one or two questions in chat? I suspect they are not worth posting a question over